# Importhtml formula in Google Sheets for web scraping

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a personal use stock metric tracker spreadsheet. I have a lot of the information already using `importhtml` from a couple of sites, but I can find the table numbers, etc. I am looking to grab data from https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history, specifically the Cash Amount column. I want to load that into columns into a spreadsheet so I can create a historical average. I've tried locating the table and using XPath on some of the tags, but keep getting an error. For quick reference, the values I'm trying to access are around line 1291 in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history",
                  "table", 3), "select Col3")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: WTF, I know I tried table 3.... I bow to you, thank you. And also giving myself a palm to forehead